# Better way to rewrite conditional sum and count query / Comparison of date ranges

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am not sure if the attempt I am doing is proper. It seems that it has to many repetitive things.

Following example operates on This Month / Previous Month, but generally I wan't to be able to set my clauses for later use for example : yesterday vs today. Its a simple comparison query. Just to make it easier for us we operate on this/last month.

My Data :

```
CREATE TABLE `incomes` (
  `income_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `area_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `added` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `gross` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `net` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `d_date` date NOT NULL,
  `added_system` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `notes` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `vat_total` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `sales_date` date NOT NULL,
  `due_date` date NOT NULL,
  `days` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `incomes` (`income_id`, `area_id`, `client_id`, `added`, `gross`, `net`, `number`, `d_date`, `added_system`, `notes`, `vat_total`, `sales_date`, `due_date`, `days`) VALUES
(48, 1, 189, 3, '172.20', '140.00', '1/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-03 16:13:21', '', '32.20', '2017-10-03', '2017-11-02', 30),
(49, 1, 189, 3, '422.44', '422.44', '2/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-03 16:15:35', 'M', '0.00', '2017-10-03', '2017-11-02', 30),
(50, 3, 216, 3, '543.50', '441.87', '22/KOM/09/17', '2017-09-29', '2017-10-04 13:02:23', '', '101.63', '2017-09-29', '2017-10-18', 14),
(51, 1, 4, 3, '625.00', '625.00', '3/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-09', '2017-10-09 16:38:27', 'D 2', '0.00', '2017-10-09', '2017-11-08', 30),
(52, 3, 441, 3, '7700.00', '7700.00', '4/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-10', '2017-10-10 17:40:51', 'B17', '0.00', '2017-10-06', '2017-10-24', 14),
(53, 2, 189, 3, '553.50', '450.00', '5/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-11', '2017-10-11 17:42:50', 'BiCHER', '103.50', '2017-10-11', '2017-11-10', 30),
(54, 3, 3, 3, '3286.06', '2671.60', '6/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-17', '2017-10-17 10:50:16', 'Int', '614.46', '2017-10-17', '2017-11-16', 30),
(55, 3, 3, 3, '5388.50', '4380.90', '7/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-17', '2017-10-17 10:51:13', 'Inska', '1007.60', '2017-10-17', '2017-11-16', 30),
(56, 3, 3, 3, '1205.40', '980.00', '8/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-17', '2017-10-17 10:52:20', 'Insa', '225.40', '2017-10-17', '2017-11-16', 30),
(57, 3, 3, 3, '1033.20', '840.00', '9/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-17', '2017-10-17 10:53:10', 'Inka', '193.20', '2017-10-17', '2017-11-16', 30),
(58, 2, 437, 3, '64.80', '60.00', '10/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-17', '2017-10-17 13:29:00', 'Nume9', '4.80', '2017-10-17', '2017-11-16', 30),
(59, 2, 406, 3, '193.21', '178.90', '11/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-17', '2017-10-17 14:23:34', '', '14.31', '2017-10-17', '2017-11-16', 30),
(60, 3, 441, 3, '3575.00', '3575.00', '12/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-23', '2017-10-23 10:43:36', 'Wyk10.', '0.00', '2017-10-23', '2017-11-06', 14),
(61, 3, 4, 3, '2000.00', '2000.00', '13/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-24', '2017-10-24 15:32:23', 'Dot./16', '0.00', '2017-10-24', '2017-11-23', 30),
(62, 3, 147, 3, '8000.00', '8000.00', '14/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-24', '2017-10-24 18:29:19', 'Dota 16', '0.00', '2017-10-24', '2017-10-31', 7),
(63, 1, 189, 3, '1395.00', '1395.00', '15/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-25', '2017-10-25 13:43:50', 'Pio&M', '0.00', '2017-10-25', '2017-11-24', 30),
(64, 4, 590, 3, '775.43', '775.43', '18/KOM/08/17', '2017-08-31', '2017-10-27 12:55:31', '', '0.00', '2017-08-31', '2017-11-10', 14),
(65, 4, 590, 3, '775.43', '775.43', '23/KOM/09/17', '2017-09-29', '2017-10-27 12:56:40', '', '0.00', '2017-09-29', '2017-11-10', 14),
(66, 1, 442, 3, '282.93', '232.46', '16/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-10-31 12:27:55', 'Uw 6', '50.47', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', 30),
(68, 1, 189, 3, '399.75', '325.00', '17/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-10-31 12:37:26', 'Wrora', '74.75', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', 30),
(69, 1, 413, 3, '469.62', '434.84', '18/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-10-31 12:41:07', 'KsaC', '34.78', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-14', 14),
(70, 2, 111, 3, '368.87', '299.90', '19/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-10-31 12:46:50', '', '68.97', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', 30),
(71, 3, 441, 3, '2178.00', '2178.00', '1/KOM/11/17', '2017-11-02', '2017-11-02 15:37:04', '16.10-20.10.2017', '0.00', '2017-11-02', '2017-11-16', 14),
(72, 3, 441, 3, '8800.00', '8800.00', '2/KOM/11/17', '2017-11-02', '2017-11-02 15:40:11', '23.10 - 27.11.2017', '0.00', '2017-11-02', '2017-11-16', 14),
(73, 1, 413, 3, '218.19', '202.03', '20/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-06 15:55:48', 'Ksa10', '16.16', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-20', 14),
(74, 1, 132, 3, '870.47', '707.70', '21/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-06 16:22:05', '', '162.77', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-14', 14),
(75, 1, 608, 3, '413.28', '336.00', '22/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-07 13:11:58', 'Łód', '77.28', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-14', 14),
(77, 1, 146, 3, '49.20', '40.00', '23/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-07 13:26:42', 'Łź 4', '9.20', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-21', 14),
(78, 1, 590, 3, '775.43', '775.43', '24/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-07 13:31:24', '', '0.00', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-14', 14),
(79, 2, 111, 3, '2460.00', '2000.00', '25/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-07 13:39:09', '', '460.00', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-21', 14),
(81, 2, 323, 3, '3095.24', '2865.97', '26/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-07 13:41:32', '', '229.27', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-21', 14),
(82, 2, 323, 3, '1103.98', '1022.22', '27/KOM/10/17', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-07 13:54:51', '', '81.76', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-21', 14),
(83, 2, 216, 3, '2827.40', '2298.70', '28/KOM/10/17', '2017-11-07', '2017-11-07 14:16:09', '', '528.70', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-21', 14),
(84, 2, 216, 3, '4737.11', '3851.31', '29/KOM/10/17', '2017-11-07', '2017-11-07 14:18:23', '', '885.80', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-21', 14),
(85, 2, 216, 3, '1966.05', '1598.42', '30/KOM/10/17', '2017-11-07', '2017-11-07 14:36:30', '', '367.63', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-21', 14),
(86, 2, 189, 3, '615.00', '500.00', '3/KOM/11/17', '2017-11-08', '2017-11-08 10:56:24', 'Aer', '115.00', '2017-11-08', '2017-12-08', 30);
```

**My query**

```
 SELECT
  Sum(CASE
    WHEN incomes.sales_date >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') AND incomes.sales_date <= Last_Day(Now())
    THEN incomes.net
    ELSE 0
  END) this_month_net,
   SUM(CASE
    WHEN incomes.sales_date >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') AND incomes.sales_date <= Last_Day(Now())
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) this_month_count,
    Sum(CASE
    WHEN incomes.sales_date >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') AND incomes.sales_date <= Last_Day(Now())
    THEN incomes.gross
    ELSE 0
  END) this_month_gross,
  Sum(CASE
    WHEN incomes.sales_date >= Date_Format(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND incomes.sales_date <=
      Last_Day(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    THEN incomes.net
    ELSE 0
  END) last_month_net,
  Sum(CASE
    WHEN sales_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ,'%Y-%m-01') AND sales_date <= LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    THEN incomes.gross
    ELSE 0
  END) last_month_gross,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN sales_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ,'%Y-%m-01') AND sales_date <= LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) last_month_count,
  incomes.area_id
FROM
  incomes

  group by incomes.area_id
```

**Query logic**

Create an aggregation for:

**This month** - *date_range1* :  that includes net sum, gross sum, count and the area_id

**Previous month** - *date_range2* that includes net sum, gross sum, count and the area_id

Current result - It can remain the same

```
   +----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
| this_month_net | this_month_count | this_month_gross | last_month_net | last_month_gross | last_month_count | area_id |
+----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
|              0 |                0 |                0 |         5635.9 |          6093.51 |               12 |       1 |
|            500 |                1 |              615 |       14625.42 |         17370.16 |               10 |       2 |
|          10978 |                2 |            10978 |        30147.5 |         32188.16 |                8 |       3 |
|              0 |                0 |                0 |              0 |                0 |                0 |       4 |
+----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
```

SQL Fiddle playground : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/482a7

Comment: What is brut sum? i think you mean brutto sum?

Comment: Wel polish isn't my laugauge i don't understand the table name and column names.. think more people will have that problem... you might want to translate the table name and column names into english for better help.

Comment: Oki all has been translated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the same result with this query:

```
SELECT
   Sum(is_current * przychody.netto)    this_month_net,
   Sum(is_current)                      this_month_count,
   Sum(is_current * przychody.wartosc)  this_month_gross,
   Sum(is_previous * przychody.netto)   last_month_net,
   Sum(is_previous * przychody.wartosc) last_month_gross,
   Sum(is_previous)                     last_month_count,
   przychody.id_rejonu as area_id
FROM
  (  SELECT *, 
            Extract(YEAR_MONTH from przychody.sprzedano)
                 = Extract(YEAR_MONTH from Now()) is_current, 
            Extract(YEAR_MONTH from AddDate(przychody.sprzedano, interval 1 month))
                 = Extract(YEAR_MONTH from Now()) is_previous
     FROM przychody
   ) AS przychody
GROUP BY przychody.id_rejonu
```

On [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e18a49/36)

When you need the current/previous selection to be today / yesterday, you would change the inner query to:

```
     SELECT *, 
            To_Days(przychody.sprzedano) = To_Days(Now()) is_current, 
            To_Days(przychody.sprzedano) + 1 = To_Days(Now()) is_previous
     FROM przychody
```

So, for different definitions of current/previous, you should find the right boolean expression for identifying a `sprzedano` as being "current" or "previous".

Comment: And what If I would like to have a more flexible access to is_current / is_previous, lets say if my where clause would change to today and yesterday? It was much easier in my example to accomplish that I think. My example is just generic this month last month but the target will be more flexible for me

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft, if your definition of `is_current` and `is_previous` changes, then you would only need to modify the logic in the inner query. Just put there what the boolean condition is for `sprzedano` to be current or previous.

Comment: Your example seems really good, but I can't adapt it to my needs, could you check https://pastebin.com/amZyRj0k , I generate such Where statements so the concept of is_current/previous is hard to implement for me. Would it be possible to do it an other way to have my clauses? To illustrate it, in this example range1 is our is_current and range2 is our is_previous

Comment: In that pastebin, "Quarter 1" is defined as just November. Are you sure that is right? Anyway you can literally take those boolean expressions and use them: `(przychody.sprzedano >= "2017-10-01" AND przychody.sprzedano <= "2017-10-31") as is_current` ... etc.

Comment: Sure, just use those expressions in the inner query as definition of `is_current` and `is_previous`.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed how to do it.

Comment: But take a look on the fiddle, the count seems be off

Comment: You have no data before 2017-08-31, so obviously the first three columns are 0. Also, the names of your last two columns need to be swapped. The count is the one without the multiplication.

Comment: Oh can I get a quality of life help also :)? could it display only records (rows ) that this_month_net > 0, I do not need them

Comment: Sure, you can append a `having this_month_net > 0` at the end, right after the `group by` clause.

Comment: Greetings trincot, are you able to help me with some query merge?

Answer (score 2):

Doing this kind of pivot work in MySQL is a well-known pain in the ... neck. In my experience sometimes it's necessary to declare victory and move on.

Still, it may be possible to simplify this kind of query by using [the `LAST_DAY()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day). It takes any datestamp expression and returns midnight on the last day of its month.  It may be able to substitute for some of your more verbose `DATE_FORMAT()` operations.

Leveraging off @trincot's approach:

Start with a subquery that adds Boolean values to your raw data. Something like this: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/482a7/11/0)

```
             SELECT LAST_DAY(sales_date) sales_month,
                    net, 
                    gross,
                    area_id
               FROM incomes
              WHERE sales_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

The `WHERE` clause in that subquery excludes records before the first day of the month before the present month. That will make your query run faster, especially if you have an index on `sales_date`.

You can then enhance that same query a bit as @trincot suggested: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/482a7/13/0)

```
         SELECT *,
            sales_month = LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) current,
            sales_month = LAST_DAY(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH) previous
          FROM (
             SELECT LAST_DAY(sales_date) sales_month,
                    net, 
                    gross,
                    area_id
               FROM incomes
              WHERE sales_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
              ) detail
```

Try this little subquery. It should give you `current` and `previous` Boolean columns, as well as the details from your `incomes` table.

Finally, use that subquery in your pivoting query, noticing that Boolean values have values 0 and 1 (in MySQL only!) and can be used to multiply other values. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/482a7/14/0)

```
SELECT SUM(net*current) this_month_net,
       SUM(current) this_month_count,
       SUM(gross*current) this_month_gross,
       SUM(net*previous) last_month_net,
       SUM(previous) last_month_count,
       SUM(gross*previous) last_month_gross,
       area_id
  FROM (
         SELECT *,
            sales_month = LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) current,
            sales_month = LAST_DAY(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH) previous
          FROM (
             SELECT LAST_DAY(sales_date) sales_month,
                    net, 
                    gross,
                    area_id
               FROM incomes
              WHERE sales_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
              ) detail
       ) subquery
 GROUP BY area_id
```

I don't know if this is better. It's definitely shorter, and it separates the various aspects of your business logic into various levels of the subquery.

Comment: And when I would like to make more complex date ranges? https://pastebin.com/NhMZVZm6 so current would be range1 and previous range2 ? seems undoable?

Comment: Why does it seem undoable? Any Boolean expression can be used. For example,  `sales_month >= '2017-01-01' AND sales_month < '2017-04-01' first_quarter` will give you a 0/1 value for sales in the first calendar quarter. You will need to adjust the `WHERE` clause if you want to consider a broader date range of sales, though.